# async await blocking, what is wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am trying to test the async/await feature of .NET. I setup a little test in LinqPad:

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test.DoStuff().Wait();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Test
{
    public async static Task DoStuff()
    {
        string s1 = "Hello 1";
        string s2 = "Hello 2";
        var s3 = await Test.Gimme();
        string s4 = "Hello 4";

        Console.WriteLine(s1);
        Console.WriteLine(s2);
        Console.WriteLine(s3);
        Console.WriteLine(s4);
    }

    public async static Task<string> Gimme()
    {
        return await Task.Run<string>(() => RetString());
    }

    public static string RetString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin");

        for (int i = 0; i < 90000000; i++)
        {
            string s = "FOO";
            s = s + s;
            s = s + s;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End");
        return "Task Hello 3!";
    }
}
```

From what I understood, I thought the code will get executed until s3 gets used again => Console.WriteLine(s3);

What am I missing?! I thought the await keyword makes it so, that the program keeps doing it's stuff, as long as the awaited result is not used.

Maybe I am implementing the Task wrong?!

Comment: `await` will wait for the awaited object to complete, how exactly this is done depends on the context but that means that `string s4 = ...` won't execute until `Test.Gimme` has completed.

Comment: If you want to achieve wanted behavior, then call `Console.WriteLine(await s3);`. This will start executing Gimme() before `s1` and `s2` are printed.

Comment: If you want to simulate work without actually writing a loop that computes useless suff, just await Task.Delay.

Comment: I am confused by your code. What is the point of `return await Task.Run...` over simply `return Task,Run,,,`? It seems strange to me that you would say "my task is to await the completion of the task of making a sandwich" when you could say "my task is to make a sandwich".

Comment: Without the await I get a sync method (compiler warning).

Comment: Never mind, I just figured I do not need the async keyword at all x_X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought the await keyword makes it so, that the program keeps doing it's stuff, as long as the awaited result is not used.

You are mistaken.  The `await` keyword will *await* that operation.  That is, instead of returning a `Task` which may complete the operation at a later time, the keyword awaits the *result* of that Task.  (Which in this case is a string.)

So when you do this:

```
var s3 = await Test.Gimme();
string s4 = "Hello 4";
```

That second line doesn't execute until the result of the `async` operation is available.  As opposed to this:

```
var s3 = Test.Gimme();
string s4 = "Hello 4";
```

Which *doesn't* wait for the operation to complete and instead just puts a reference to the `Task<string>` in `s3`, which may complete (be awaited) at a later time.

The idea here is that the `DoStuff()` method *itself* will execute code in the order in which it is imperatively written, just like any other code.  But something *invoked* by that code is potentially asynchronous, and so code which in turn invokes `DoStuff()` has the option of handling it in an asynchronous manner.

Most `async` methods are logically synchronous, but wrap underlying asynchronous operations and expose the option to higher levels to not block on those operations.  Keeping the mantra that things should be "async all the way down", many such methods offer "pass-through ascynchronicity" and allow the top-level UI to handle bottom-level I/O asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, a big detail, totally got it wrong. Now I am wondering why LinqPad  puts an "awaiting..." in the console and replaces it later on...

Comment: I get that it's doing it because it gets delayed ... guess it's a nice LinqPad feature.

Answer (score 5):

> What am I missing?! I thought the await keyword makes it so, that the program keeps doing it's stuff, as long as the awaited result is not used.

You are correct; your confusion is what "doing its stuff" means. The "stuff" that is done while you are awaiting the result is the "stuff" of the **caller** of DoStuff, which is Main.  What does the caller do while DoStuff cannot make progress because the task is not completed?  **It calls Wait**.  So that's what happens!

You said that you wanted to await the result, meaning that you want the caller to do whatever it does while the task is being processed asynchronously. And the caller says "I have nothing to do but wait synchronously*.  If the caller did some other work before calling Wait on the task, then you would see that work being done.

Comment: Damn ... you're right, guess I mixed it up somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Await actually holds execution until the process if fully complete. So, your test method should fully build out the whole RetString, then return that to Gimme, then Gimme will return the string to var s3, then processing continues.

From Microsoft: The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes. The task represents ongoing work. Further details found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx